# Entity deleted yet it gives error - When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Consider the following tables:

```
public class User
{
    public long user_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; } = new List<Tag>();
}

public class Tag
{
    public long tag_id { get; set; }
    public long user_id {get; set; }  // foreign key to User table
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; } = null!;
}

//Note: This POCO class is not created in code but rather present as SQL Table. 
//Included here as a reference
public class UserTag
{
    public long tag_id { get; set; }  // foreign key to Tag table
    public long user_id {get; set; }  // foreign key to User table
}
```

DBContext.cs

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.user_id);

            entity.ToTable("User");

            entity.HasMany(d => d.Tags)
                .WithMany(p => p.Users)
                .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                    "User",
                    r => r.HasOne<Tag>().WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("tag_id"),
                    l => l.HasOne<User>().WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("user_id"),
                    j =>
                    {
                        j.HasKey("user_id", "tag_id");
                        j.ToTable("UserTag");
                    }); 
        });
```

Now we are removing all the tags before saving new tags. I understand that this is not an efficient operation but would still like to understand why its not working:

```
//Before the code below is executed 
//somewhere else `user` was created and `new_tag` as displayed below was linked to the `user`.
//Then only the following code is executed


var new_tag = new Tag()
                  {
                      tag_id = 1,
                      name = "Tag 1"
                  };

var user = db.Users
             .Include(x=> x.Tags)
             .First(x => x.user_id == user_id);

// Remove old tags completely
var list_to_remove = user.Tags.ToList();

foreach (var tag in list_to_remove)
{
   user.Tags.Remove(tag);
}

await db.SaveChangesAsync();

// Add new tag
user.Tags.Add(new_tag);

await db.SaveChangesAsync();   // Get error here if removed tag is same as the new one
```

Error on adding the same tag again:

> When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Then see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). When I try to test your code, I get a different exception message "The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s)".

Comment: What line are you facing the exception? It points to the fact that SaveChanges is being triggered when there is nothing to save. It seems like you haven't linked a tag to the user and hence you are facing this error.

Comment: I get the exception at the second `SaveChanges()` line. Since I get a different exception you should add a MCVE, so everyone who try to help or reproduce the problem actually get the same exception as you do.

Comment: @Progman have added the relevant DBContext code part, can you check now. The question now should have all the needed parts to reproduce the error. If it still doesn't work would create a github repo to reproduce

Comment: The SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables are still missing. It looks like there is even a third table/entity involved? Do not create a github repo, the MCVE should be in the question.

Comment: Actually with the defined DBContext there was no need for a POCO class for UserTag but added it as a reference for SQL Table.

Comment: You need to clear the change tracker between deleting and adding the same entity.

Comment: @CodeCaster can you please share as an answer, not sure how to achieve that

Comment: I can't. Search "entity framework clear change tracker".

Comment: Tried clearing change tracker with `context.ChangeTracker.Clear();` now there is no error but the Tag is no longer added to User

Comment: Because you don't add it to the user?

Comment: Following the same code as above doesn't work. I have to fetch the user again after clearing change tracker and then add tag

Comment: You shouldn't add a new Tag but an existing Tag (attached as unchanged). Your goal is to create new `UserTag` records, not new tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mixing two different relationships, a one-to-many:

User.Tags /w Tag.User

and a many-to-many:

```
        entity.HasMany(d => d.Tags)
            .WithMany(p => p.Users)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "User",
                r => r.HasOne<Tag>().WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("tag_id"),
                l => l.HasOne<User>().WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("user_id"),
                j =>
                {
                    j.HasKey("user_id", "tag_id");
                    j.ToTable("UserTag");
                }); 
    });
```

These are not compatible. Your code for removing a tag and re-adding will work in the case of a one-to-many relationship, though you might first need to ensure that the removed entity is detached from the DbContext as the DbContext may still end up tracking the removed instance:

```
foreach (var tag in list_to_remove)
{
   user.Tags.Remove(tag);
   db.Entry(tag).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

However, this won't work in a many-to-many relationship with a UserTag association. If a user has many tags, and a tag can be associated with many users via the UserTag table, then the first thing is to remove the UserId / User reference from the Tag entity:

```
public class Tag
{
    public long tag_id { get; set; }
//    public long user_id {get; set; }  // foreign key to User table
    public string name { get; set; }

//    public virtual User User { get; } = null!;
}
```

You could have a collection of Users for listing any users that share this tag, which is implied in your WithMany mapping:

```
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; } = new List<User>();
```

Handling updating tag references on a user record needs to be done a bit more carefully rather than trying to remove everything and re-add it. For instance if I pass in an updated set of Tag IDs to associate to the user (updatedTagIds):

```
var user = db.Users
    .Include(x => x.Tags)
    .Single(x => x.UserId == userId);

var existingTagIds = user.Tags.Select(x => TagId).ToList();
var tagIdsToAdd = updatedTagIds.Except(existingTagIds).ToList();
var tagIdsToRemove = existingTagIds.Except(updatedTagIds).ToList();
if(tagIdsToRemove.Any())
{
    var tagsToRemove = user.Tags
        .Where(x => tagIdsToRemove.Contains(x.TagId))
        .ToList();

    foreach(var tag in tagsToRemove)
         user.Tags.Remove(tag);
}

if(tagIdsToAdd.Any())
{
    tagsToAdd = db.Tags
        .Where(x => tagIdsToAdd.Contains(x.TagId))
        .ToList();
    foreach(var tag in tagsToAdd)
        user.Tags.Add(tag);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

This isn't deleting "Tags" but behind the scenes it is adding and removing UserTag rows as needed for tags that we identify need to be removed or added.